# is it possible to have $u(1,t) = 10$ and $u(x,0) = x^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$? (heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I was looking over a problem that asks for the physical interpretation of a partial differential equation ($u_t = u_{xx}$ for $x \, \in \, (0,1)$, $t \geq 0$).

But the problem gives a boundary condition:

$$u(1,t) = 10, \hspace{0.35cm} \text{ for $t > 0$},$$

and the initial condition:

$$u(x,0) = x^2, \hspace{0.35cm} \text{ for $x \, \in \, [0,1{\color{red}]}$} $$

Am I mistaken in believing that this initial condition should have been stated as:

$$u(x,0) = x^2, \hspace{0.35cm} \text{ for $x \, \in \, [0,1{\color{red})}$} $$

instead? Since the boundary condition at $x=1$ requires $u(1,0) = 10$, 
or is this fine because the boundary condition is for $t > 0$ (which doesn't include $t = 0$)?

I doubt it's of importance to the concepts at hand, I was just curious.

Comment: Mathematically there is no problem, but this implies that there will be a discontinuity. Physically, discontinuities are rather rare.

Comment: Funny, I thought it might've been the other way around: I figured physically it could represent a bar / wire with an initial temperature distribution which is then set in a environment that creates the boundary conditions (insulated on left, heat bath on the right). So the wire had $u = 1$, but the heat bath had $u = 10$. Now that I think of it, though - that would mean the temperature instantaneously changes from 1 to 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial conditions should really be stated inside of the domain, not including the boundary: $u(x, 0) = x^2 $ for $x\in (0, 1)$.  That's because the solution is really defined on an open set, and the boundary conditions are a statement about the limits of $u(x, t)$ as $x$ approaches a boundary point.

But it's common to gloss over all this in textbooks. One point does not make a difference anyway (unless there is a point source / Dirac delta in there).

So, the boundary conditions make sense and can be satisfied, with the understanding that there will not exist a limit of $u(x, t)$ as $(x, t) \to (1, 0)$. At very small scale, the behavior of $u(x, t)$ near $(1, 0)$ will be complicated and not really consistent with physics (transfer of energy at unbounded rate). But ignoring that tiny bit, the rest of the function will be reasonable.

Comment: Would you be able to point to a source (physical or online) that addresses this formality? I've marked it as correct, but would be interested in learning more. Thank you very much for taking the time to post such a clear answer.